# Error while connecting Elastic Map Reduce ruby client

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, elastic-map-reduce

I am following the steps mentioned on the AWS to use an interactive Hive session using SSH.
I used the following resources

1. https://github.com/ucbtwitter/getting-started/wiki/Using-Elastic-Map-Reduce-via-Command-Line
2. http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/GettingStartedGuide/SignUp.html

I was getting this error initially **"Error: Missing key access-id"** and then I fixed my JSON file. The JSON file is in the same format as mentioned in the above links.

When I run this command

```
./elastic-mapreduce
```

I am getting the following error :-

**Error: Unable to parse credentials.json: can't convert String into Integer.**

I checked the values required in JSON at AWS as well.

Does anyone has an idea why am I getting this error?

Comment: unless you show us a resemblance of your JSON file (with dummy credentials, not your real ones), it is all a guessing game.

Comment: @claudia 
This is the format of my JSON file.
   [
     { 
        "access-id":      "AKUEQIDLSNWHEYRHDS7E",
        "private-key":   "8SJEUWusiEW/6wRTE",
        "key-pair":       "mykey.pem",
        "key-pair-ﬁle":   "/User/asquare/hadoop/mykey.pem",
        "log_uri":        "s3n://file/log",
        "region":         "us-east-1",
     }
   ]

Comment: Your last "," seems to be the problem. Try your JSON with a validator, e.g. http://jsonlint.com/ and you'll notice that it does not validate with the dangling "," after the region key/value pair. Remove the "," and it validates.

Comment: @claudia I checked the file I put the comma by mistake. I was able to use the interactive hive client using SSH.

Answer (score -1):

The region value in the credentials.json must be of int type.

```
{......
......
"region": 1
}
```